# How to Integrate html with ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am working on the reactjs project.

**what happened**

I have following reactjs code written into javascript file.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import ReactBootstrap, { Jumbotron, Container, Row, Col, Column, Image, Button } from 'react-bootstrap';


class Homepage extends Component {
  render() {

    return (
    <aside id="fh5co-hero">
        <div class="flexslider">
            <ul class="slides">
            <li style="background-image: url(../../Assets/images/img_bg_1.jpg);">
                <div class="overlay-gradient"></div>
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 text-center slider-text">
                            <div class="slider-text-inner">
                                <h1>abc</h1>

                                    <p><a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" href="#">Start Learning Now!</a></p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li style="background-image: url(images/img_bg_2.jpg);">
                <div class="overlay-gradient"></div>
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 text-center slider-text">
                            <div class="slider-text-inner">
                                <h1>abc</h1>
                                    <p><a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-learn" href="#">Start Learning Now!</a></p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li style="background-image: url(images/img_bg_3.jpg);">
                <div class="overlay-gradient"></div>
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 text-center slider-text">
                            <div class="slider-text-inner">
                                <h1>abc</h1>
                                    <p><a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-learn" href="#">Start Learning Now!</a></p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
      </aside>


  );
  }
}

export default Homepage;
```

**what is issue**

when i try to compile using npm start , it throws following error :

> Error: The `style` prop expects a mapping from style properties to
>   values, not a string. For example, style={{marginRight: spacing +
>   'em'}} when using JSX.
>       in li (at homePage.js:13)
>       in ul (at homePage.js:12)
>       in div (at homePage.js:11)
>       in aside (at homePage.js:10)
>       in Homepage (created by Context.Consumer)

not able to understand, how to integrate html code into reactjs router dom. is this something `style` issue OR the version mismatch issue.

version details :

```
react": "^16.12.0",
"react-bootstrap": "^1.0.0-beta.16",
```

please suggest.

Comment: [Styling and CSS - React](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-styling.html). [Styling DOM Elements](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#style). The docs are always a good place to start.

Comment: Why the question has negative voting. ? please remove it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ReactJs uses JSX instead of html (https://reactjs.org/docs/introducing-jsx.html).  There are some differences, for example,  instead of "class" you must use "className". Instead

> style="background-image: url(images/img_bg_2.jpg)";

you must use

> style={{backgroundImage: 'url(images/img_bg_2.jpg)'}}

Your code should look like this:

```
   <aside id="fh5co-hero">
    <div className="flexslider">
      <ul className="slides">
        <li style={{backgroundImage: 'url(../../Assets/images/img_bg_1.jpg)'}}>
          <div className="overlay-gradient" />
          <div className="container">
            <div className="row">
              <div className="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 text-center slider-text">
                <div className="slider-text-inner">
                  <h1>abc</h1>
                  <p><a className="btn btn-primary btn-lg" href="#">Start Learning Now!</a></p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li style={{backgroundImage: 'url(images/img_bg_2.jpg)'}}>
          <div className="overlay-gradient" />
          <div className="container">
            <div className="row">
              <div className="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 text-center slider-text">
                <div className="slider-text-inner">
                  <h1>abc</h1>
                  <p><a className="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-learn" href="#">Start Learning Now!</a></p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li style={{backgroundImage: 'url(images/img_bg_3.jpg)'}}>
          <div className="overlay-gradient" />
          <div className="container">
            <div className="row">
              <div className="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 text-center slider-text">
                <div className="slider-text-inner">
                  <h1>abc</h1>
                  <p><a className="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-learn" href="#">Start Learning Now!</a></p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </aside>
```

Answer (score 1):

This code `<li style="background-image: url(../../Assets/images/img_bg_1.jpg);">`

Should be `<li style={{backgroundImage: 'url(../../Assets/images/img_bg_1.jpg)'}}>`

The `style` prop in React expects an object and not a CSS string.

Answer (score 1):

by default react( aka: JSX ) can't have inline styles like what you pasted therem you need to convert them to JSS style like below:

```
// for example "background-image: url(images/img_bg_3.jpg);

<li style={{ backgroundImage: 'url(SOME_IMAGE_URL)' }}> ... </li>
<li style={{ backgroundImage: `url(${IMPORTED_IMAGE})` }}> ... </li>
```

Answer (score 0):

The style attribute is written in react js as follows

```
style={{
      display: 'flex',
      flexDirection: 'row',
      justifyContent: 'space-between',
}}
```

Note that we can't use dash between words (-) `flex-direction` is turned to `felxDirection` and so on
also the value has to be put inside single or double quotes